# Precision error when finding eigenvalues of Hecke operator

Tags: precision, sage, eigenvalue

I am trying to use SageMath to calculate the p-adic valuations
of the eigenvalues of the Hecke operator, but I am having some
issues. I am using the following code to calculate them:

```py
p = 5
F = Qp(p, prec=10000)
v = valuations.pAdicValuation(F, 5)
R.<X> = PolynomialRing(F)
S.<T> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
SHOW_FACTORS = False

for m in [52 .. 53]:
    hs = hecke_series(p, 2, 2, m)
    print(f'\nm = {m}\nhecke series = {hs}')
    for root, mul in S(hs).roots(ring=F):
        print(f'root {v(root)}')
    if not SHOW_FACTORS:
        continue
    try:
        print('Factors:')
        for f, mul in R(hs).factor():
            print(f)
    except:
        print('*** factorization failed ***\n')
```

But I have found that for different precisions `m`,
I do not get the same results. For example, for `m  = 52`
and `m = 53`, I get different sets of valuations.

```py
m = 52
hecke series = 248689957516035065054893493652343750*x^13 + 1674403001743485219776630401611328125*x^12 + 1158477226609946228563785552978515625*x^11 + 1681565410974239751696586608886718750*x^10 + 740816027146591471840858459472656250*x^9 + 984876153765252102828224029541015625*x^8 + 2199502199510497526175470605761718750*x^7 + 2047190245401796728083458292414140625*x^6 + 227766241144299957275576934742803125*x^5 + 1626265950251135133773358227520486875*x^4 + 2173838516487905357643185902479851120*x^3 + 966441077617202989620226898790437136*x^2 + 2033736385834117114445851281601109243*x + 1
root 9
root 7
root 4
root 2
root 1
```

```py
m = 53
hecke series = 4689582056016661226749420166015625000*x^13 + 3894849050993798300623893737792968750*x^12 + 1158477226609946228563785552978515625*x^11 + 1681565410974239751696586608886718750*x^10 + 740816027146591471840858459472656250*x^9 + 7646214301516191345370014038085937500*x^8 + 6640394298011123687869997278125000000*x^7 + 10928974442403049051472511637140703125*x^6 + 4668658339644926118970103607106084375*x^5 + 3846711999501448214620621563702127500*x^4 + 4394284565738218438490449238661491745*x^3 + 3186887126867516070467490234972077761*x^2 + 2033736385834117114445851281601109243*x + 1
root 9
root 7
root 5
root 5
root 4
root 2
root 1
root 0
root 0
```

I know for a fact that they should be giving the same valuations, however.
Indeed, the valuation of the roots should be the same because of the
properties of [Newton polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon)
as long as the polynomial for `m = 53` reduces modulo `p^52` to the
polynomial for `m = 52`. I tested this, using the following code:

```py
hecke_series(5, 2, 2, 52)

R.<q> = PowerSeriesRing(ZZ,default_prec=p*100)
Poly.<x> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)

def ordred2(a, p):
    b = Poly(a)
    # ensure we have enough coefficients to avoid issues with list index
    b += x^(14)
    ordred2_b = b.coefficients(sparse=False)
    ordred2_coeff = list('ordred2_coeff_%d' % d for d in range(14))
    for i in range(14):
        ordred2_coeff[i] = Mod(ordred2_b[i], p^52)
    return R(ordred2_coeff)

ordred2(hecke_series(5, 2, 2, 53), 5)
```

And found that it does indeed reduce. However, I did notice that if I use

```py
R.<q> = PowerSeriesRing(ZZ, default_prec=p*10)
```

instead, then it does not reduce properly. This seems to indicate to me
that there is some sort of precision error that I am running into
in this problem, but no matter what I change in my code, I seem to get
the same result when calculating the valuations. Indeed,
for `Qp(p, prec=100)` and `Qp(p, prec=10000)`, I get the same result.
Am I missing something? Is there some other place I have to increase
the precision, which I am not seeing?